# Repeating an action forever with a global function

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, repeat, skaction

I have a rectangle that needs to be constantly moving up, but is also declared globally like so so that I can call it in multiple places:

```
   var obstacle = SKNode!

  override func didMoveToView {
     obstacle = rectangle()
    }


  func rectangle() -> SKNode {
   let rect = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rectangle@x2")
    rect.size = CGSizeMake(30, 30)

    rect.position = CGPointMake(210, -250)
    rect.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.littleRect
   rect.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.bigRect
    rect.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
   rect.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: rect.size)
    rect.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    rect.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    rect.runAction(
        SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 1200,
            duration: NSTimeInterval(6.5)))

    addChild(rect)
    return rect

}
When I attempt to run it as an action repeating forever like so, i get the error "cannot convert value of type SKNode to argument runBlock" : 

   runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(rectangle),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(4.0)])))
```

So is there a way to declare this sort of action for a function set up like this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this `var obstacle = SKNode!` will produce an error. You should  declare an implicitly unwrapped optional like this:

```
 var obstacle:SKNode!
```

About the main question (without analyzing the logic of what code actually does,)...You are passing an instance of `SKNode` class to [+runBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/runBlock:) method (which accepts a closure), thus the error. To fix this, you have to pass a closure, like this:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock({[unowned self] in self.rectangle()}),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(4.0)])))
}
```

Comment: @IHeartAppsLLC remember to also upvote if you feel this is the correct answer once you get the ability to upvote.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks for the edit. But you made a mistake with a part "explicit unwrapped optional". The term is "implicitly unwrapped optional" because it implicitly unwraps the optional's value (removes the need for check & and unwrap ).

Comment: @Whirlwind ahh,  thought that was for  unwrapping without declaring the name,  good call, learned something new